# How to See Hibernate in the Power Setting Correctly?

Tags: 13.10, power-management, settings, hibernate

I enabled hibernate and it works. Also I can see hibernate option in the system menu and in the power setting as an option of "When power is critically low". However I cannot see hibernate in the power setting as an option of "When the lid is closed" which has only "Suspend" and "Do nothing" options. Can I add hibernate as an option for "When lid is closed" setting?

Answer (score 0):

Open dconf editor. (If not installed run `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools` in the terminal)

Navigate in dconf editor to: org>gnome>settings-daemon>plugins>power

I here there are options for things such as when the lid closes with all options. Change to Hibernate.

Comment: If you change them to Hibernate, power setting shows empty. When the lid is closed, it just suspends.

Comment: Yes it should be blank in the power settings after this. You are sure you didn't change it back in the power dialoge? Also there are two versions of lid closed (AC and battery) you did the correct one?

Comment: I just looked it and dconf still shows hibernate for both lid-close ac and battery action.